# Unable to retrieve the process id of the Android App through adb

Tags: android, adb

For my project purpose, I want to fetch the process id of the app running on the smartphone. I installed an app from the Play store and after installing, when I launch the app, I am unable to get the process id of the app with the help of the following command `adb shell pidof packageName`.The app is still running, but I am not getting the process id.

For all the other apps, I am able to get the process id with the above command mentioned.

Does anyone know why it happens and what are the other alternatives to fetch the process id of the running app on the Android device?

Thanks for the help

Comment: and what's the result when you invoke `adb shell pidof packageName` against your project's app?

Comment: @Lino I got no output. This is the app which I am referring to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.axis.mobile&hl=en_US&gl=US
You can also try installing and try to fetch the pid. Plz let me know, if you are able to get

Comment: answer updated. You can try for instance `adb logcat|grep -i axis`

Comment: is the answer below helping to get the PID?

Comment: we can do a guess, but I am just curious to know why sometimes pidof is not working.  I wanted to have a concrete answer w.r.t if we execute a particular command, then we are getting the process id of the app

Comment: good, understood